# SQLAlchemy - ModuleMarker Errror on certain table classes

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a simple class that accesses a table for storing run times.
However when I try to import the class I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: '_ModuleMarker' object has no attribute 'add_item'
```

I have been able to determine it is something to do with setting up the table name and columns as I have 2 other classes accessing two different tables and it is working fine there.
I basically copy pasted the code from the 2 original classes so I am not sure why it doesn't work.

Is there a way I can produce a more helpful error code?

**RunTimes Class**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres@localhost/reseller', encoding='utf-8', pool_size=50, max_overflow=200)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

Base = declarative_base()

class RunTimes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'run_times'
    store = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    start_time = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    end_time = Column(TIMESTAMP)

    def __init__(self, store):
        self.store = store
        results = session.query(RunTimes).filter(RunTimes.store.like(store)).first()
        self.start_time = results.start_time
        self.end_time = results.end_time

    def Update(self):
        session.merge(self)
        session.commit()
```

**test.py**

```
from RunTimes.RunTimes import RunTimes
rt = RunTimes("Store")
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and it turned out that this error arose because my class that inherited from `Base` had the same name as the python file, and python package where it was defined.
 Here I can see from your **`test.py`** that it's also the case. Try having different names for the package, the file and the class.

Comment: have had same issue, your advice helps!